# Group statistic

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping

I want to make `DataGrid` with grouping like below
[image]

My question is how to do that "Average value" in group header?

Below is a huge xaml

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Grid.Column="1" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding List}" HeadersVisibility="Column" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding A}" Header="A"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding B}" Header="B"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding C}" Header="C"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Group}" Header="Group"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0.5" CornerRadius="4" Margin="3">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FFACACAC" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="B"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ItemCount}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="test" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                            <Expander>
                                                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0.5" Margin="3">
                                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                                </Border>
                                            </Expander>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Which produces this output

[image]

I can output group name (green arrow) and counter (red arrow).

How can I output average value for either column (let it be `A`) instead of "test"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a converter to convert the `Items` property into the average. Something like this:

```
public class ItemsToAverageConverter : IValueConverter {
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                                       CultureInfo culture){
    var propName = Convert.ToString(parameter);
    var items = (IEnumerable<Item>) value;
    var prop = typeof(Item).GetProperty(propName);
    if(prop == null) return Binding.DoNothing;
    return items.Average(i => (double) prop.GetValue(i));
  }
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                                                       CultureInfo culture){
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

I suppose the item type is `Item`. You use that converter in your XAML code, maybe you need some `StringFormat` to format the value representation.

Suppose you have this resource somewhere accessible:

```
<local:ItemsToAverageConverter x:Key="avgConverter"/>
```

The code should be changed like this:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Items,
                                  Converter={StaticResource avgConverter},
                                  ConverterParameter=A,
                                  StringFormat=f2}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: There are few mistakes in given code (`ConvertBack`, Cast<Item>, `Convert.ToString`, maybe more - I simplify reflection to `switch / case` so didn't try to run a complete sample), but gives idea about how to achieve that. Thanks. The only question left is what to do if `Items` can change? Is there an easy way to *refresh statistic when group items change*? Currently it looks like value is converted only once - when group is created. `CollectionView.Refresh()` works, but it's brutal way and I have to handle edits, etc.

Comment: As I am using converters for the first time (!) I found [this hint](http://drwpf.com/blog/2009/03/17/tips-and-tricks-making-value-converters-more-accessible-in-markup/) to be very useful (to reduce xaml *noise*). Also in `StringFormat={}{0:f2}` you can escape brackets like this `StringFormat=\{0.00\}`, I believe it is more clear than that `{}` fix.

Comment: @Sinatr yes, there are at least 2 ways to escape, I also know about the second way.