# ListView multiline column header with different types of data in ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26712051/1997232) question.

I want to implement this kind of `ListView`:

[image]

It should have 2 things:

1. Multiline column header;
2. Different data types bound via `ItemsSource` to be displayed differently.

---

To solve (1) I try to use `HeaderTemplate`:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="A" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding A}">
                <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
...
```

`DataTemplate` can be more complicated:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Grid.Row="1" Columns="{StaticResource ResourceKey=aaa}"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Where `aaa` is a key of some `GridViewColumnCollection`:

```
<GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="aaa">
    <GridViewColumn Header="B" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding B}"/>
    <GridViewColumn Header="C" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding C}"/>
 </GridViewColumnCollection>
```

This, however, produces poor result:

[image]

It looks ugly on mouse-over, re-sizing `B` will only change `C`, but not `A`.

**Question: how to make multiline column header properly?**

---

To solve (2) I try to switch templates based on value of item property `Mode` (when it's 2 - use:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mode}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="PART_Panel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding D}"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding E}" Margin="5,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
...
```

It works, I can use `ObservableCollection<object>` to bind 2 types of object (one has A, B, C properties and another D, E, both types also has `Mode` property), but..

[image]

It has visual issues with `Mode = 2` items. `ListView` appearance (called *Vista*) is not inherited, only `Mode != 2` items have it. I am talking about mouse-over highlight and selecting item, when doing such with `Mode = 2` items selection looks like this:

[image]

`A-AA` is mouse-overed (but *nothing* is highlighted) and `B-BB` has *keyboard* focus (selected with arrow keys, if I try to click on it with mouse, it's also *nothing*).

Of course, I can add triggers, but to do what? Changing background color? It doesn't looks *Vista* at all! Here I tried to use default `ListViewItem` template colors:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="PART_Panel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
...
```

But result is.. disappointing:

[image]

Notice difference: `2-22-222` is selected (*Vista* style) and ugly `A-AA` too.

**Questions: How to display different data types bound as `ItemSource` properly? How to keep nice *Vista* style on?**

P.S.: I apologise for a bit (or much) long question. I could split it into several, but my intent is to implement that complete `ListView` and I feel all those are related (removing anything may make this to be solved in simplified way, unsuitable for a complete solution).

Comment: How sure are you that you want that kind of display? You might have to render things yourself for something so specific. :s

Comment: @ThorSummoner, I am not sure, but I am opened to ideas and compromises. If I would have to *render things myself*, how would I do that? I've made few owner-drawn controls in wpf already, but `ListView` looks quite complicated to me, especially drawing things like *Vista style*.

Comment: Yeah its going to be complicated, but it shouldn't be too bad if you have a firm idea of how you want things to look. I don't know how to do anything in wpf specifically; but If you already found a way to draw custom controls you'll probably need to do something similar, calculating out all the space for all the things you want to display and the rules for how they wrap and draw. But since that's so tedious that's why ListViews are provided. If it is at all possible, I'd encourage you to try to use ListView in its most conventional way; Or possibly construct something using grid layouts. :\

Comment: Second problem is solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28274838/1997232) (more or less), multiline column header is still opened or, alternatively, is there a way to **control columns width of row, which content is inside `Canvas` and unbound to normal columns**?. I will probably ask separate question and then will delete this one.